# Setting up Admin directory in Laravel

Tags: controller, laravel, admin

I'm learning Laravel but have hit a snag while trying to create an "admin" section for a little blog application.

In my routes I have:

```
 Route::get('admin', 'Controllers\Admin\IndexController@getIndex');
```

And in my Controllers directory I have an "admin" directory with a IndexController.php file with this:

```
class IndexController extends \BaseController
{

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getIndex()
{
    return "hello";
}
}
```

When I try to go to mydomain.com/admin I get an error stating:

```
ReflectionException
Class Controllers\Admin\IndexController does not exist
```

How can that be possible? Thanks for any pointers you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered I need to run composer's dump-autoload command to get it to work. It does now. Don't understand why but it does.

Comment: `composer Dump-autoload` just dumps the autoload files, so your newly added directory/files are being auto loaded now.

Comment: Thanks. I just added my admin directory to the start/global.php directories. Apparently that will prevent my need to dump so often as I work.

Comment: If you use `psr-0` autoloading in your `composer.json` file then you don't need to `dump-autoload` everytime you add new classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Laravella, it has a Content Management System and Admin section built in :

https://github.com/laravella/laravella/releases